# Consulta y validación de datos en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

tengo el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo tres tablas las cuales son `inventario, entrada y salida` en las tablas hago las siguientes consultas y me dan como resultado:

`inventario`

```
  SELECT * FROM inventario

    idInventario  nombre  descripcion
    ------------  ------  -----------
               1  A8      Alambre
               2  A9      Alambre
               3  A10     Alambre   
               4  A11     Alambre 
               5  A12     Alambre
```

`entrada`

```
 SELECT productoID, SUM(cantidad) AS suma FROM entrada GROUP BY productoID
    
    productoID    suma  
    ----------  --------
             1       100
             2       120
             3        30
             4        60
```

`salida`

```
SELECT productoID, SUM(cantidad) AS suma FROM salida GROUP BY productoID

productoID    suma  
----------  --------
         1        90
         2        32
         3        20
         4        15
         5         5
```

En mi codigo php quiero que me muestre todos los productos que hay en inventario pero que salga la suma de cada uno, algo asi

```
idInventario  nombre  descripcion  sumaEntradas  sumaSalidas
------------  ------  -----------  ------------  -----------
           1  A8      Alambre              100      90
           2  A9      Alambre              120      32
           3  A10     Alambre               30      20
           4  A11     Alambre               60      15
           5  A12     Alambre                        5
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
echo "idInventario; nombre; sumaE; sumaS <br>";
        foreach ($dataInv as  $dataInv) {
            echo  $dataInv["idInventario"]."; ";
            echo  $dataInv["nombre"]."; ";
            echo  $dataInv["descripcion"]."; ";

            foreach ($dataTEntrdas["tEntradas"] as  $dataTEntrdas) {
            if ($dataInv["idInventario"] ==  $dataTEntrdas['productoID']){
               echo $dataTEntrdas['suma']."; ";
            }}

            foreach ($dataTSalidas["tSalidas"] as  $dataTSalidas) {
                if ($dataInv["idInventario"] ==  $dataTSalidas['productoID']){
                   echo $dataTSalidas['suma']."; ";
                }}
                        echo "<br>";
        }
```

Esta es la salida que obtengo

```
idInventario; nombre; descripcion; sumaE; sumaS
         1;       A8;    Alambre;    100;   90;
         2;       A9;    Alambre;
         3;      A10;    Alambre;
         4;      A11;    Alambre;
         5;      A12;    Alambre;
```

Como ven los primeros si me trae las sumas correspondientes pero de los demas item no, al ver los array  `var_dump($dataTEntrdas["tEntradas"]);`  `var_dump($dataTSalidas["tSalidas"]);` estan en `NULL` no se porque.

Que esta mal en mi codigo y si hay una forma de hacer la consulta desde la base de datos directamente mucho mejos y como lo haria ya que desde un principio intente hacerlo asi pero me fue imposible o no di yo con la solucion.

Comment: Como sabe el sistema que ```1  A8      Alambre``` tiene de entrada  ```100``` y de salida ```90``` ?

Comment: Ah ya vi, es que la tabla la tienes como inventario pero en otros sitios lo llamas como producto id. en estos casos tendrias que utilizar inner join

Comment: Si, ya intente la consulta con innerJoin el problema es que como son 2 tablas que referencia a la tabla inventario al hacer inner join no me trae todos los datos ya que una tabla puede tener mas registros que la otra. No se si me hago entender o como lo harías, ilustrarme.

Comment: Mañana te dare una respuesta para ver si te sirve ok? ahorita no puedo pero si tengo una solucion

Comment: Listo colega, gracias por la ayuda, espero tu aporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mejor obtener los resultados esperados a nivel de SQL. Para ello sólo tienes que sumar las entradas en una sub-consulta, las salidas en otra y en cada una hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con la tabla `inventario`.

Vamos a verlo en el siguiente fiddle:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventario (
  idInventario INT,
  nombre VARCHAR(10),
  descripcion VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO inventario  VALUES 
(1,'A8','Alambre'),
(2,'A9','Alambre'),
(3,'A10','Alambre'),
(4,'A11','Alambre'),
(5,'A12','Alambre');

CREATE TABLE entrada (
  productoID INT,
  cantidad INT
);

INSERT INTO entrada  VALUES 
(1,50),
(1,50),
(2,50),
(2,70),
(3,15),
(3,15),
(4,40),
(4,20);

CREATE TABLE salida (
  productoID INT,
  cantidad INT
);

INSERT INTO salida  VALUES 
(1,60),
(1,30),
(2,16),
(2,16),
(3,10),
(3,10),
(4,10),
(4,5),
(5,5);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT  
    i.idInventario, 
    i.nombre,
    i.descripcion,
    e.sumaEntradas, 
    s.sumaSalidas
FROM    inventario AS i
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT productoID, SUM(cantidad) AS sumaEntradas
            FROM entrada 
            GROUP BY productoID
        ) AS e ON  i.idInventario = e.productoID 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT productoID, SUM(cantidad) AS sumaSalidas 
            FROM    salida
            GROUP BY productoID
        ) AS s ON i.idInventario = s.productoID;
```

| idInventario | nombre | descripcion | sumaEntradas | sumaSalidas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A8 | Alambre | 100 | 90 |
| 2 | A9 | Alambre | 120 | 32 |
| 3 | A10 | Alambre | 30 | 20 |
| 4 | A11 | Alambre | 60 | 15 |
| 5 | A12 | Alambre |  | 5 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hp88EzoPVYVQQiYiQi8XPB/0)